# Пустая строка не должна соответствовать регулярному выражению

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
 System.out.println("".matches("[a-zA-Z]{2,20}||[а-яА-Я]{2,20}"));
```

Почему данная строка выводит true? длина строки же 0,  а строка мне должна вернуть тру, если хотя бы одно из выражений верно, а они же получается оба false?

По одному то строки выводят false:

```
 System.out.println("".matches("[а-яА-Я]{2,20}"));
 System.out.println("".matches("[a-zA-Z]{2,20}"));
```

Answer (score 6):

В вашем первом регулярном выражении 3 (ТРИ) выражения. Я их для наглядности выделил круглыми скобками:

```
([a-zA-Z]{2,20}) | () | ([а-яА-Я]{2,20})
```

Вам нужно сделать вот так:

```
System.out.println("".matches("[a-zA-Z]{2,20}|[а-яА-Я]{2,20}"));
```